Terraform - can't connect to ec2
I have following terraform code that creates ec2 instance in eu-north-1 and transform traffic from port 8080 to port 8080
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-north-1"
}
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-0249211c9916306f8"
  instance_type = "t3.micro"
  user_data     = <<-EOF
              #!/bin/bash
              echo "Hello, World" > index.html
              nohup busybox httpd -f -p 8080 &
              EOF
  tags = {
    Name = "terraform-example"
  }
  user_data_replace_on_change = true
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.instance.id]

}

resource "aws_security_group" "instance" {
  name = "aws security group"
  ingress {
    from_port   = 8080
    to_port     = 8080
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

I get following IP address from this:
    private_dns                          = "ip-172-31-37-14.eu-north-1.compute.internal"
    private_ip                           = "172.31.37.14"
    public_dns                           = "ec2-13-60-37-183.eu-north-1.compute.amazonaws.com"
    public_ip                            = "13.60.37.183"

I try to use curl or web browser to get to 13.60.37.183
➜  ~ curl http://13.60.37.183:8080                                         
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 13.60.37.183 port 8080 after 36 ms: Couldn't connect to server

and I can't. I tried to create my own VPC group but still the result is the same.

is there any ACL on the subnet the instance is in? Generally timeouts like this indicate something it dropping the traffic, Either aws ACL, aws SG or something like iptables or ufw on the ami its self

I would ssh into the instance to ensure the user data script actually ran successfully, and started up the httpd server. You can check that in the /var/log/cloud-init-output.log log file. I don't know what ami-0249211c9916306f8 has pre-installed, but you aren't installing the Apache web server as part of your script, you are assuming it is installed already on the AMI.
